# Ruby on Rails - Get rid of milliseconds on Active record t.timestamps columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, timestamp

I've created a `phrases` table, which by default ActiveRecord has added two columns: `created_at` and `updated_at`.

```
class CreatePhrases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :phrases do |t|
      t.string :phrase
      t.string :emotion
      t.string :category

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I am sharing this database, and the `updated_at` column values look like this currently:

`2014-03-12 20:53:26.846635`

I need to remove the milliseconds off of this column. Each value, which is created automatically when a record is updated, should look like this:

`2014-03-12 20:53:26`

How can I drop the milliseconds off of this column?

Answer (score -1):

Is this just for output purposes?  If so, you might just look in to overwriting the output method.  Something like this in your view-

```
def created_at
  read_attribute(:created_at).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end

def updated_at
  read_attribute(:updated_at).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end
```

Then put that in a concern and share it amongst your models.

Comment: Good idea, but actually this DB is being shared and the data is being ported into another SQL database. Whatever form of SQL is being used on the other end requires timestamps to cut off the milliseconds. The solution proposed now is to convert my Postgres timestamp to a varchar(23) and cast is back as a datetime...It's just getting really hacky and would be better if I could just eliminate the milliseconds from my DB.

Comment: Yeah, the conversion to a timestamp would work.  Though, if your data set is large enough going through all records in all tables and doing the conversion could be interesting.